# Add SONAR_RUNNER_HOME correctly to PATH

Tags: macos, bash, path

I'm trying to use sonar-runner in my Mac.
So i download SonarScanner and follow the instruction here : http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner

When i try to run " sonar-runner " in my terminal i've got this message :

```
sonar-runner: command not found
```

I think it's a problem of adding SONAR_RUNNER_HOME to my path. So i edited my .bash_profile file like this :

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
export PATH
# add custom, local installations to PATH
PATH=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:"$PATH"
PATH=/usr/local/sonarqube-5.3/bin/macosx-universal-64:"$PATH"
PATH=/usr/local/Documents/sonar-scanner-2.5/bin:"$PATH"
PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:"$PATH"
```

With this, Maven work, i can use " mvn test " for example. But not for " sonar-runner " ...

I've edit the .profile file to like this :

```
 JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home
 export JAVA_HOME;

 SONAR_HOME=/Users/Max/Documents/sonarqube-5.3/bin/macosx-universal-64/
 export SONAR_HOME;

 SONAR_RUNNER_HOME=/Users/Max/Documents/sonar-scanner-2.5/bin
 export SONAR_RUNNER_HOME;

 M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.9
 export M2_HOME;
```

Finally, i try to edit the /etc/paths file like this :

```
 /usr/local/bin
 /usr/bin
 /bin
 /usr/sbin
 /sbin
 /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin
 /Users/Max/Documents/sonar-scanner-2.5/bin
 /Users/Max/Documents/sonarqube-5.3/bin/macosx-universal-64/
```

Always the same problem...
Can someone can explain me how to fix it and add correctly my sonar_runner_homme to the path ?

thanks !

---

FIXED

It was just a bad way : PATH=/usr/local/Documents/sonar-scanner-2.5/bin:"$PATH"
                        PATH=/usr/local/sonar-scanner-2.5/bin:"$PATH"

My bad !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was caused by a wrong path entry. Unlikely to be of use to future readers.

Comment: This actually helped me